# Unexpected memory dump on C structure

Tags: c, linux

Set C structure as follows:

```
    struct test {
    char name[20];
    };
```

When dumping it byte by byte before it gets initialized with the following code:

```
 struct test real_name;
 raw_ptr = (char*) &real_name;
 for(i=0; i < sizeof (real_name); i++)
 printf("raw_ptr [0x%016lx]\t0x%02x\n",
            (unsigned long int)&raw_ptr[i],
            (unsigned int)raw_ptr[i]);
```

I am getting following output:

```
    raw_ptr [0x00007ffe5211d780]    0x40
    raw_ptr [0x00007ffe5211d781]    0x57
    raw_ptr [0x00007ffe5211d782]    0x08
    raw_ptr [0x00007ffe5211d783]    0xffffffa8 <-
    raw_ptr [0x00007ffe5211d784]    0xffffff82 <-
    raw_ptr [0x00007ffe5211d785]    0x55  
    ...
```

My question is why two marked lines are shown in size of *eight* bytes instead of *two*?

Comment: because you *TELL* printf that it's a pointer to an unsigned int value -- just UB. The `ff` values are the result of sign extending. Use `hh` as length modifier to address bytes. Of course, still UB, reading something not initilized. So why answer here ...

Comment: What is `raw_ptr`? You never show its definition.

Comment: Eight bytes? If you mean the latter value, you’re casting things and int is 32bit in your machine so it’s shown as such.

Comment: FelixPalmen> That's not the point. The value he has trouble with is the second one, the  `%02x` specifier. And the issue doesn't come from the specifier, it comes from performing sign extension on the char value.

Comment: Changing to this: `(unsigned int)(unsigned char)raw_ptr[i]` should eliminate the issue. In fact, `(unsigned char)raw_ptr[i]` should do the trick.

Comment: @spectras Or, if `raw_ptr` is a `char*`, use the correct format `%02hhx` and skip the casting.

Comment: I think reading the documentation of `prinf()`, how the given width is just a minimum, and how it expects a signed int, would have helped. But anyway, what is the real use case? Reading an unintialised object is UB, so the results are supremely uninteresting. Just doing random stuff with code and then asking why weird things happen does not seem very productive.

Comment: @spectras sloppy question, sloppy comment ;) Yes, looking at the code, it already happens when converting the value ...

Comment: @underscore_d thank you for taking time to reply. I am learning, and this is the part from, from you permission I will continue

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the definition is `char *raw_ptr`

Answer (score 0):

I expect `raw_ptr` is defined as `char` and it seems that in your environment `char` is signed (please note: signedness of char data type is implementation defined).

So on your `(unsigned int)raw_ptr[i])` expression the `signed char` is casted to `unsigned int` but before that the value is promoted to an `int` that also implies that the sign has to be extended to the appropriate data type size.
Then after the call it is impossible for print to only use 2 characters so it ignores your width specifier.

Comment: And as I commented, you can examine what happens when replacing the conversion with `(unsigned char)`, which will avoid the sign extension. And then use SomeProgrammerdude's advice and do the right thing: use the correct specifier (`%02hhx`).